# How to exit from git:(master) ✗?

Tags: git, macos, terminal, zsh

How do I exit from "git:(master) ✗" from my mac terminal. I have latest version of **zsh**, **git**,  installed with default theme "robbyrussell". I tried multiple ways, `$ cd .`, `$ cd ~`, `$ git rm .git` but nothing helped. Could anyone of you please help me in fixing it?. Below is the output I see when I run `$ git rm .git`

Output:

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ git rm .git
fatal: pathspec '.git' did not match any files

➜  ~ git:(master) ✗
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Thanks for the fancy formatting, you put passion in it. Try to use pre-defined formatting though, as it will be maintained in the future by the site. Could you better explain how you ended up in this situation? Why are you trying to delete .git?

Comment: Start with `git rev-parse --git-dir`. `mv $(git rev-parse --git-dir) .git-backup`

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @Bunty : If you want to delete your git repository, you have to do it using `rm -r .git`.  Your `git rm .git` would work if `.git` were a regular file managed by git, but it is a special directory which git uses to manage the repository.

Comment: Thanks @user1934428, your suggestion worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below steps worked;

➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ `pwd`

/Users/bunty_home

➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ `cd ..`    *(this command is to exit out of git repository)*

➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ `rm -r .git`

override r--r--r--  bunty_home/staff for .git/objects/pack/pack-f76e6a02ba4d161b1b453179ba12835649ce2ace.pack?

*Pressed `Enter` a couple times to agree all the questions like above*

➜  ~

➜  ~ `pwd`

/Users/bunty_home

Comment: This answer is confused. by going to the parent folder with `cd ..` and removing the `.git` folder in _all_ child folders with the `-r` option you are telling people that it is ok to destroy all local copies of their repositories on their machines, potentially.

Answer (score 2):

I'll attempt to answer based on what I can imply from your question.

You don't exit git. What the terminal is telling you is that you are in a git repository, on branch master.
You created the repository: either by a clone, or by a copy and paste or via `git init`. If you `cd ..`, unless parent folder is also a repository, you should no longer see the git notice. Congrats, you "exited" git!

How do you un-version a git-versioned repository? Just delete the .git folder inside it. This way it will no longer be a git repository.

Comment: Hi Daemon,
I confirm that I'm not in a git repository. I ran "cd .." to exit out of git repo but guess what, I still see "git:(master) ✗". however suggestion from @user1934428 "rm r .git" worked when I ran it after exiting git repo.

Comment: if you were able to remove (`rm`) a .git folder, that was a repository. A folder is a git repository if it contains a .git folder with certain files inside. Git just "scan" the folder looking for the .git manifesto and then prompts you the fact you _are_ in a repo in the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge, Daemon. I could verify the i'm in the home directory of my mac hard drive but I use to still see this "git:(master) ✗" in this path. So I ran "rm -r .git" at the home directory level and it worked out. I verified the status of git after running, and everything seems to be smooth.